# Is there a notation similar to $\times$ for an operator that produces set pairs instead of ordered pairs?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $A = \{a,b,c\}$. We can use the $\times$ operator to produce:

$A \times A = \{(a,a),(a,b),(a,c),(b,a),(b,b),(b,c),(c,a),(c,b),(c,c)\}$.

is there a simple operator similar to $\times$ that produces:

$A * A = \{\{a,a\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,b\},\{b,c\},\{c,c\}\}$?

Comment: Well, $$A*A=\left\{\cup S\mid S\in A\times A\right\}$$

Comment: I wanted to avoid defining my own operator, if possible - was just checking if there already existed something that was in common use. Seems weird to me that there wouldn't be!

Comment: I'm not asking you to. I'm just saying the one on the right is short and what you want.

Comment: It's short, but its not a simple symbol like $\times$. I was just asking if there was some form of notation that was a simple symbol like $\times$ that did what i was asking. But evidently there isn't!

Comment: Just a question about your solution though, isn't an ordered pair a set, i.e., $(a,b) = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$? If so, then wouldnt $A * A = \{\{\{a\}\},\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\},\{\{a\},\{a,c\}\},\{\{b\},\{a,b\}\},\{\{b\}\},\{\{b\},\{b,c\}\},\{\{c\},\{a,c\}\},\{\{c\},\{b,c\}\},\{\{c\}\}\}$, the way you have defined it? Or am I misreading what you wrote? I suppose you could say $A*A = \{\cup T \mid T \in S \in A \times A, |T| > 1 \}$, but then that becomes a bit messy..

Comment: With the Kuratowski definition $ (a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ we have $z\in (a,b)\iff [z=\{a\}\lor z=\{a,b\}]$.... And $x\in \cup (a,b)\iff$ $ \exists z\in (a,b)\, (x\in z)$ $ \iff [x\in \{a\}\lor x\in \{a,b\}]\iff $ $[x=a\lor x=b]\iff$ $\iff x\in \{a,b\}$... So $\cup (a,b)=\{a,b\}.$

Comment: In set theory $[A]^k$ denotes the set of all subsets of $A$ that each have cardinality $k,$  where $k$ may be a finite or infinite cardinal. And note that $\{a,a\}=\{a\}.$ So we can say $A*A=[A]^1\cup [A]^2.$

Comment: Also in set theory $[A]^{\le k}$ denotes the set of subsets of $A$ that have cardinality $k$ or less. So $A*A=[A]^{\le 2}\setminus \{\emptyset\}.$

Comment: Cool! that is very interesting. Thanks a lot for that.. it looks like i have a bit of reading to do. However, I think the answer to my initial question is "no", hehe..

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I would be slightly careful with that though, especially if the paper is not set theory related to define the terminology beforehand.